# Selective static compilation with QtCreator

Tags: qt4, static-libraries, qt-creator, static-linking

I'm with QtCreator under ubuntu 64 bit and Qt4.

I'm using the `boost::filesystem` lib for a project and I would like to statically compile only this one into the final executable, I still haven't found a way to adopt a selective statically compilation or a way to specify to Qtcreator that I want only `boost::filesystem` to be statically compiled and everything else can be dynamic.

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) mar dic 25 07:27:22 2012
######################################################################

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += . \
               ~/libs/boost_1_52/include
LIBS += -static -L~/libs/boost_1_52/lib \
        -lboost_filesystem

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I have tried to place the `static` flag everywhere without results, even the `Bdynamic` and `Bstatic` flags.

Is this possible in QtCreator ?

Comment: The question you should be asking is: "Is it possible *without* Qt Creator?" Can you come up with a link command that does what you want? Because if it's not possible in general, then Qt Creator (or rather, qmake) can't do anything about it to begin with.

Comment: @NikosC. I haven't think about it, since I'm trying to solve this for this project only I haven't thought about this. But I think that this should be possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this other than not having a shared library but only a static one. If you have both, then the linker will pick the shared one and it doesn't seem to be possible to switch that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about linking directly the *.a file instead of using `static -L~/libs/boost_1_52/lib 
        -lboost_filesystem` ...?